# Auto refreshing unlimited divs

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, refresh

I am currently able to refresh a div on my website using jquery with php.  This works well to a point.  The issue is that the data being refreshed currently is an entire table.  The code being used in the header is as follows:

```
<!-- DIV REFRESH START -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script> 
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function()
{
$('#datatable').fadeOut('slow').load('data/table.php').fadeIn("slow");
}, 10000);
</script>
<!-- DIV REFRESH END -->
```

As you can see, it is refreshing a specific div with a specific page.  I'm very novice with jquery and java based coding in general as I'm sure will be evident in this question.

Is it possible to do the following:

1. The table is actually created in a php function due to the the fact that the number of rows changes all the time.  Is it possible to have it refresh the function specifically rather than a page that is just calling the function?
2. The table currently refreshes completely.  This is just to update one figure on each row.  It would be much cleaner to have it only refresh each figure on the row but due to the flexible nature of the table and the fact that it is part of a function would this be possible?  If so, how would it be possible?  I know I could have each div on each row to have a unique div name which I could then take into account in the script section at the top of the page but would that not require having every possible div name added with the same code repeated?
3. Though I know it is possible to have the item refresh based on when something in the database changes rather than by a time delay but what would be the best way given the requirements listed above?

I could be way off and it's a simple answer to each question but I appreciate any and all input.

Thanks!

p.s. if it helps, the function I'm currently using to create the table is the following (I know it can be made to function much cleaner but it is a bit of a learning project):

```
function portalTable($venueId, $eventId)
{   
    echo "<table class='basic-table'><tr class='th'><th>Portal Name</th><th>Scanned</th></tr>";
    $grandTotals = array();
    $portalSql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM portal WHERE id_venue = $venueId");
    while ($portalRow = mysql_fetch_array($portalSql))
        {
            $portalId = $portalRow['id_portal'];
            $portalName = $portalRow['name_portal'];
            if($portalId&1) {$gray = "dg";} else {$gray = "lg";}                        
            $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM scan WHERE id_event = $eventId AND id_portal = $portalId");
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
                {
                    $scanTotal = $row['total_scan'];
                    echo "<tr class='$gray'><td>$portalName</td><td>$scanTotal</td></tr>";
                    $grandTotals[] = $scanTotal;
                }
        }
    $totals = array_sum($grandTotals);
    echo "<tr class='basic-table-total'><td>Total</td><td>$totals</td></tr>";

    // total failed scans
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT total_errors FROM errors WHERE id_event = $eventId");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
        {
            $totalErrors = $row['total_errors'];
            echo "<tr class='basic-table-total'><th>Total Rejected Scans</th><th>$totalErrors</th></tr>";
        }

    echo "</table>";
}
```

Comment: You need to use AJAX, and have your PHP return structured data (e.g. JSON or XML) that the Javascript processes to know how to update the table. Designing this is not a quick thing I can write in an answer, but maybe using an MVC framework for your application would simplify it.

Comment: He is already using AJAX, read about jQuery.load(...) -- and it actually IS a quick thing that can be wrote in an answer -- read about jQuery.parseJSON(....)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('div.myDiv').each(function(i, obj) {
    $(obj).load('myURL.php');
});
```

That what you're looking for?

As for the large amount of data being sent? Don't send raw HTML!
Instead, use [parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) in jQuery and [json_encode](http://php.net/json_encode) in your PHP script to send a (much) smaller amount of data to the user, which can then be used by the client to make the table.

Handling the decoded JSON data is relatively simple in JavaScript. Once it has been decoded, it is now an accessible `object`. You can use an iterator (jQuery does this well).

```
$.each(myJSON, function(i, val) {
    $('body').append(val + "<br />");
});
```

Comment: I've used json previously but I'm not sure I understand how to use it in this context.  Also, I'm not exactly clear on how the above code utilises it to achieve the desired result. (sorry, not too well versed in java yet)

Comment: well versed in javascript* Java and JavaScript are entirely different things :) Read updated post in a few minutes

Comment: well that says a lot about my experience with them so

Comment: Thanks for this, it's helping a lot but I'm still having difficulty understanding what is contained in the JSON data to be decoded.  I can use this code and do more reading on the subject to understand what I'm doing with it.  Much appreciation though.

Comment: Hi David,  Thanks for your help but I still can't seem to get my head around applying your answer to the issue.  Can you give me a bit more info on what way you would go about applying it?  Thanks

Comment: What does the JSON data that you receive from the URL you load look like?

Comment: my issue lies in figuring out how I'm to use JSON with this issue so there is currently no JSON data.

Comment: The same way you're building your table in PHP. Obviously, the table that comes from your PHP code must rely on an array of data? A result set from your database perhaps?

Comment: sorry, slowly getting you now.  Yes, the table is created based on the data received from a call to the database.  For each result a row is created.  Are you suggesting adding the results of the call to a JSON and creating the table from that?

Comment: `By George, I think you've got it!`. Yep, that's exactly what you'll want to do :)

Comment: ok, I'll give it a go.  What is the advantage of doing it this way? And how will it allow me to have multiple divs which can each refresh independently of each other for each bit of data?

Comment: As I said, it's actually for your worry about the amount of data being retrieved each time. To reload each div independently ignore anything I said after "As for the large amount of data being sent"

Comment: thank christ, I was really confused as to how one related to the other!  ok.  How the hell do I use this in the current situation to have it that each row that is created (which is one div for each result on the table) and have each div refresh independent of each other?